# Multi Step Form Custom Validation

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to write my own multi-step form jquery validation (mostly because I've never done it before and would like to learn). For some reason I can't seem to get even the first step to process.  Here is my JQUERY and you can find the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c28pdLof/

```
$('#msform .first').click(function() {

    $("#instanceTitle").each(function(){
        if ($($this).val() == '') { 
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $('#msform .first').preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        }

});
```

Comment: `$($this)` I think this should give you `$this is undefined` error

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting that error but I am getting an Unexpected End Of Input error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check number of opening and closing brackets and curly thingies

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Apparently this block of code doesn't like the "this":

```
if ($(this).val() === '') {
```

and instead this works:

```
if ($('#instanceTitle').val() === '') {
```